# M & Power Query: How to use the $Skip ODATA expression within a loop?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Good afternoon all,

I'm trying to call all of the results within an API that has:

- 6640 total records
- 100 records per page
- 67 pages of results (total records / records per page)
- This is an ever growing list so I've used variables to create the    above values.

I can obviously use the $Skip ODATA expression to get any one of the 67 pages by adding the expression to the end of the URL like so (which would skip the first 100, therefore returning the 2nd page:

```
https://psa.pulseway.com/api/servicedesk/tickets/?$Skip=100
```

What I'm trying to do though is to create a custom function that will loop through each of the 67 calls, changing the $Skip value by an increment of 100 each time.

I thought I'd accomplished the goal with the below code:

```
let 

    Token = "Token",
    BaseURL = "https://psa.pulseway.com/api/",
    Path = "servicedesk/tickets/",
    RecordsPerPage = 100,

    CountTickets = Json.Document(Web.Contents(BaseURL,[Headers = [Authorization="Bearer " & Token],RelativePath = Path & "count"])),
    TotalRecords = CountTickets[TotalRecords],


    GetJson = (Url) =>
        let Options = [Headers=[ #"Authorization" = "Bearer " & Token ]],
            RawData = Web.Contents(Url, Options),
            Json = Json.Document(RawData)
        in  Json,

    GetPage = (Index) =>
        let Skip    = "$Skip=" & Text.From(Index * RecordsPerPage),
            URL     = BaseURL & Path & "?" & Skip,
            Json    = GetJson(URL)
        in  Json,

    TotalPages       = Number.RoundUp(TotalRecords / RecordsPerPage),
    PageIndicies    = {0.. TotalPages - 1},
    Pages           = List.Transform(PageIndicies, each GetPage(_))

in
    Pages
```

I got all happy when it successfully made the 67 API calls and combined the results into a list for me to load in to a Power Query table, however what I'm actually seeing is the first 100 records repeated 67 times.

That tells me that my GetPage custom function which handles the $Skip value isn't changing and is stuck on the first one. To make sure the Skip index was generating them properly I duplicated the query and changed the code to load in the $Skip values and see what they are, expecting them all to be $Skip=0, what I see though is the correct $Skip values as below:

[Image showing correct Skip values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr43X.jpg)

It seems everything is working as it should be, only I'm only getting the first page 67 times.

I've made a couple of posts on other community site around this issue before but I realise the problem I was (poorly) describing was far too broad to get any meaningful assistance. I think now I've gotten to the point where I understand what my own code is doing and have really zoomed in to the problem - I just don't know how to fix it when I'm at the final hurdle...

Any help/advice would be massively appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:  Updated following @RicardoDiaz answer.

```
let

    // Define base parameters

    Filter  = "",
    Path    = "servicedesk/tickets/",
    URL     = "https://psa.pulseway.com/api/",
    Token   = "Token",
    Limit   = "100",

    // Build the table based on record start and any filters

    GetEntityRaw = (Filter as any, RecordStart as text, Path as text) =>

        let 

            Options     = [Headers=[ #"Authorization" = "Bearer " & Token ]],
            URLbase     = URL & Path & "?bearer=" & Token & "&start=" & RecordStart & "&limit=" & Text.From(Limit),
            URLentity   = if Filter <> null then URLbase & Filter else URLbase,
            Source      = Json.Document(Web.Contents(URLentity, Options)),
            Result      = Source[Result],
            toTable     = Table.FromList(Result, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)

        in
            toTable,

    // Recursively call the build table function

    GetEntity = (optional RecordStart as text) as table =>

        let
            result      = GetEntityRaw(Filter, RecordStart, Path),
            nextStart   = Text.From(Number.From(RecordStart) + Limit),
            nextTable   = Table.Combine({result, @GetEntity(nextStart)}),
            check       = try nextTable otherwise result

        in
            check,
            resultTable = GetEntity("0")
in
    resultTable
```

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't test your code, it's kind of hard to provide you a concrete answer.

Said that, please review the generic code I use to connect to an api and see if you can find where yours is not working

EDIT: Changed api_record_limit type to number (removed the quotation marks)

```
let
    // Define base parameters
    api_url_filter = "",
    api_entity = "servicedesk/tickets/",
    api_url = "https://psa.pulseway.com/api/",
    api_token = "Token",
    api_record_limit = 500,
    // Build the table based on record start and any filters
    fx_api_get_entity_raw = (api_url_filter as any, api_record_start as text, api_entity as text) =>
    let
        api_url_base = api_url & api_entity & "?api_token=" & api_token & "&start=" & api_record_start & "&limit=" & Text.From(api_record_limit),
        api_url_entity = if api_url_filter <> null then api_url_base & api_url_filter else api_url_base,
        Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(api_url_entity)),
        data = Source[data],
        toTable = Table.FromList(data, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
    in
        toTable,
    // Recursively call the build table function
    fxGetEntity = (optional api_record_start as text) as table =>
    let
        result = fx_api_get_entity_raw(api_url_filter, api_record_start, api_entity),
        nextStart = Text.From(Number.From(api_record_start) + api_record_limit),
        nextTable = Table.Combine({result, @fxGetEntity(nextStart)}),
        check = try nextTable otherwise result
    in
        check,
        resultTable = fxGetEntity("0"),
        expandColumn = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(
                    resultTable,
                    "Column1",
                    Record.FieldNames(resultTable{0}[Column1]),
                    List.Transform(Record.FieldNames(resultTable{0}[Column1]), each _)
                )
in
    expandColumn
```

---

**QUESTION TO OP:**

Regarding this line:

```
Result      = Source[Result],
```

Does the json return a field called result instead of data?

[image]

Comment: Good morning Ricardo, thank you very much for your reply. I've been editing the code to fit my scenario and this is what I've come up with:

Comment: Had to create a new answer to share my edited version of your code, I hope you don't mind me reformatting, I tried to make it a bit more visually clear.

Comment: You can [edit] your question and delete your answer if the code you have still doesn’t work. Just let me know.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, I've updated the post with my revised code. It successfully calls the first 100 records / first page, but no more.

Comment: Please remove quotation marks in the `api_record_limit` definition