# How to iterate/loop through next pages in an API request in PowerQuery/PowerBI?

Tags: pagination, powerbi, powerquery, m

The API am working with gets called and returns data like below (tried from postman):

Example call 1:

```
https://api.aaaaaa.com/api/v1/survey?step=1&limit=1000
{
    "_links": {
        "base": "http://api.aaaaaa.com",
        "self": "/api/v1/survey?step=1&limit=1000",
        "next": "/api/v1/survey?step=2&limit=1000"
    },
    "start": 1,
    "limit": 1000,
    "size": 1000,
    "total": 3158,
    "results": [
        {....//data
         }
]
```

Example call 2:

```
https://api.aaaaaa.com/api/v1/survey?step=2&limit=1000
{
    "_links": {
        "base": "http://api.aaaaaa.com",
        "self": "/api/v1/survey?step=2&limit=1000",
        "prev": "/api/v1/survey?step=1&limit=1000",
        "next": "/api/v1/survey?step=3&limit=1000"
    },
    "start": 1001,
    "limit": 1000,
    "size": 1000,
    "total": 3158,
    "results": [
        {....//data
         }
     ]
```

In Power BI/Power Query am trying to iterate over to get the next link and append/combine with the base API url to fetch next page/set of records.

However, am only getting 1 page in the list i.e. GeneratedList {0}. Whereas, from the Postman response it can be seen that it has 3 pages (step=1,2,3). So, was expecting to return 3 values in the list for each page. Here's the code:

```
let 
   BaseUrl = "https://api.aaaaaa.com",
   SurveyUrl = Text.Combine(BaseUrl,"/api/v1/survey?step=1&limit=1000"),
   Options = [ApiKeyName= "TOKEN"],
   url = Web.Contents(SurveyUrl, [Headers=[TOKEN="zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"]]),

 FnGetOnePage =
  (url) as record =>
   let
   Source = Json.Document(url),
   data = try Source[results] otherwise null,
   next = try Source[_links][next] otherwise null,
   res = [Data=data, Next=Text.Combine(SurveyUrl, next)]
   in
    res,
 
 GeneratedList =
  List.Generate(
   ()=>[i=0, res = try FnGetOnePage(url) otherwise null],
   each [res][Data]<>null,
   each [i=[i]+1, res = try FnGetOnePage([res][Next]) otherwise null],
   each [res][Data])
   in
    GeneratedList
```

Please suggest/help in where am getting it wrong in the above steps ??

Another approach I could think of is to directly loop/iterate over **step number value** in the url i.e.  ...

> /api/v1/survey?step=<**loop_over_this_number**>&limit=1000

; but haven't tried. So, any suggestions are most welcome.

Reference:- https://datachant.com/2016/06/27/cursor-based-pagination-power-query/

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Have a look at the code I use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68021742/1521579

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz - No luck !! Copied the entire code and replaced (1) &start with &step, (2) source[data] with source[results] and (3) limit=100 to limit=1000...rest part of the code remains same (except base parameters). However, it still returns only 1st set/step of 1000 rows and doesn't fetch beyond that :(

Comment: Uploaded a pic of the updated/changed code in original post above, after referring to the link & code you provided.

Comment: Ok. Let me check

Comment: Please remove quotation marks in the api_record_limit definition and check your api documentation to set it to the correct value

Comment: The max limit is 1000 records per call as per api docs. Also, removed the quotes (" ") from the limit variable value, but still no luck and unable to fetch next set of 1000 records.

Comment: In the meanwhile, I went ahead with the simplest approach of considering "&step" as pages and iterating over it using List.Generate. However, would really be interested in understanding how we can do it using "next" link approach returned from the API calls. May be I need some more time & practice to dig into that a bit :). thanks!